# Working Out JavaScript Time with PHP Time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working on a page that pulls data from DB. PHP `time()` is captured and saved to the DB alongside user contents.

I want to be about to subtract the `capturedTime` from the current time using JavaScript and display how long the post has been made in `hr : min : s` and should be live.

**HTML:**

```
<div class = 'responses'>
   <p class = 'capturedTime' style='display: none;'>123456789</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).on('click', '.responses', function () {
     $this = $( this );
     timeC = $this.prev('.capturedTime').text();
     timeNow = $.now()
     timeLapsed = ( timeNow - timeC )/1000;
     seconds = timeLapsed/60;
     mins = seconds/60;
     hrs = mins/24;
     if ( timeLapsed !== NaN ){
         alert(seconds + '------' + mins + '---' + hrs);
     }
 });
```

Comment: `$.now()` will give you milliseconds. PHP's `time()` gives you seconds; that's one thing you'll have to sort out.

Comment: @oGeez: If I do that, how can I make it count up?

Comment: Apologies I misunderstood the idea of your code. Are you just testing to see how long it has been since the element was first loaded? I wouldn't want to compare timestamps from the server with those on the client.

Comment: No. I am trying to display how long the post has been made. Just like that of Twitter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to change your code this way:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wk3eP/8/)

```
<body>
    <div class='responses'>
        <p class='capturedTime' data="1401270715145"></p>
    </div>
</body>






var $times, timer;

$times = $('.capturedTime');
timer = setInterval(function () {
    var i, len, cache, value, now, minutes, seconds;

    for (i = 0, len = $times.length; i < len; i = i + 1) {
        cache = $times.eq(i);
        now = new Date().getTime();
        value = new Date(now - parseInt(cache.attr("data")));
        minutes = value.getMinutes();
        seconds = value.getSeconds();
        cache.html("m:" + minutes + " ss:" + seconds);
    }

}, 1000);
```

Comment: Offcourse you can customize the shown timing as well as refresh rate as you like.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://timeago.yarp.com/jquery.timeago.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var lastUpdate = new Date($(".capturedTime").html()*1000)
        alert($.timeago(lastUpdate));
         });                
</script>
```

or visit this [page](http://timeago.yarp.com/)